# Acquired "at" vs "with"

Tags: prepositions

Is it correct to write:

> "skills acquired *at* large companies.."

Can **"at"** in this sentence be interchanged with the word **"with"**?

Comment: More context required. "Skills required at large companies" and "skills required with large companies" are both grammatically acceptable, but mean subtly different things. Have you looked up the definitions of "at" and "with" in a dictionary? What did you find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the question.

*As I don't have enough reputation, I reply to this as an "answer" instead of a "comment".*

In this sentence, *"at"* is not interchangable with *"with"*.

You should imply **where you have acquired your skills** according to the meaning of the sentence.

I hope this answers your question well.

Comment: I will give you an example and please correct me if I am wrong. "I have acquired the skills with a large organization". I want to express that the experience I have was accumulated in a large organization.

Comment: If the experience you have was accumulated in a large company, you should be trying to say "where" have you had the chance to acquire the skills, rather than "how" have you acquired. For instance, "I have acquired the skills at a large company with professional guidance, an outstanding performance and attention on the job."